# iOS send a local notification after receiving a silent remote notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

When the server sends a silent notification, I want to check if the user is in the right state and then issue a local notification as a result if the user is in the right state or do nothing if the user is not in the right state.

Is this feasible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you send the push notification with `"content-available": 1` it will be a silent push (see Apple's [local and remote notification guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)).

You then want to conditionally schedule a local notification with `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add()` and implement the delegate methods for `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea.
The system treats background notifications as low-priority.
proof: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

So background notification is not for you case.
**If you don't want show notification** for some cases, you just in
implementation method of *UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate* don't call completion handler:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
guard self.shouldShowNotification(notification) else { return } // don't call completion handler if we're don't want to show push
completionHandler(.alert)
}

func shouldShowNotification(_ notification: UNNotification) -> Bool {
  if ... {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```